# Operator== overload

Tags: c++, overloading, bigint

I'm doing a project for school and where I need to create a bigint class and it has 4 requirements thus far.

1.) Write a method to write a bigint that prints at most 80 digits per line.

2.) Write a method to compare if two bigints are equal. It should return a bool.

3.) Write a method to initialize a bigint to an int value you provide [0, maxint].

4.) Write a method to initialize a bigint to a char[].

I think I have 2 and 3 correct, but I'm having trouble with comparing two bigints and I was hoping that someone could lead me in the right direction on how to limit print to 80 digits per line.

Here's my code so far:

.h file

```
class bigint
{
public:

bigint(); //default constructor

bool operator==(const bigint& num1); 

bigint( int n);

bigint(char new_digits[]);


private:
    int digit[MAX];
    int digitb[MAX];

};
```

here is the implementation file:

```
#include "bigint.h"
#include<cassert>
#include<iostream>


//default constructor
bigint::bigint()
{
     for (int i = 0; i < MAX; i++) 
     {
    digit[i] = 0;
     }

     }


     bigint::bigint( int n )
     {
    int i = 0;



      while(n > 0)
    {
       digit[i] = n % 10;
       n = n /10;
       ++i;
break;
     }


  for(i; i< MAX; ++i)
      digit[i] = 0;


     }

 bool bigint::operator==(const  bigint& num1)
     {

       for(int i = 0; i < MAX; i++)
          {
        if (num1.digit == num1.digit)
              return true;
          }
        return false;

      }


   bigint::bigint(char new_digit[])
      {
     int i = 0;

         //Reads the characters of numbers until it is ended by the null symbol

            while(new_digit[i] != '\0')
             ++i;

             --i;

       //Converts the characters into int values and puts them in the digit array
         while( i >= 0)
    {
            digit[i] = new_digit[i] - '0';
            --i;
    }


}


}



int main()
  {

     #include<iostream>

using namespace std;
using PROJECT_1::bigint;

bigint a(0);

assert(a == 0);
  }
```

BTW, I'm not trying to get the answers for my homework that I just started an hour ago.  I've been working on this all day and I finally gave in and asked for help.

Comment: A) Please format your code correctly rather than apologizing about it. The editor isn't that hard to master B) This really isn't a "do my work for me" site; after making your post readable, explain what you've tried or at least what your current line of thinking is. People are more than willing to help if those two things are provided.

Comment: Oh, and operator== always returns true.  The issue is in the line:
        if (num1.digit == num1.digit)
There are other issues - my first question is: What is the representation of the "digit" array?  More specifically, does "digit[0]" host the most significant digit or the least significant digit?

Answer (score 1):

The contents of the loop inside `operator==` is not working. What you are doing is comparing the `digit` array (which technically is a pointer) of `num1` with the `digit` array pointer of `num1`. This will always be true. You should be comparing each index in `this->digit` to the corresponding index in `num1.digit`. something like this:

```
bool bigint::operator==(const  bigint& num1)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < MAX; i++)
    {
        if (digit[i] != num1.digit[i])
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

As you can see, I also changed the comparison from equal to not-equal. This is because otherwise if only the first digit is the same in both `bigint` objects then using equal would have the function return `true` after only checking the first digit.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of problems with your code.  The most immediate one
has been pointed out: the expression on both sides of the `==` operator
is identical, so naturally the function returns `true`.  The most
idiomatic way of writing this function in C++ would be:

```
return std::equals( 
    std::begin( digit ), std::end( digit ), std::begin( num1.digit ) );
```

In professional code, I would consider anything else poor programming.
In a sudent assignment, it's less clear, since one of the goals may be
to learn how to write such things yourself, and you may not be allowed
to use the standard algorithms in such cases.  I'd still go for the same
basic approach, however, using “iterators”, rather than 
indexes:

```
int const* current = std::begin( digit );
int const* other   = std::begin( num1.digit );
int const* end     = std::end( digit );
while ( current != end && *current == *other ) {
    ++ current;
    ++ other;
}
return current == end;
```

As for the rest of the code:

- `operator==` should definitely be `const`; otherwise, even something as simple as `myBigInt == 0` won't work.
- In fact, `operator==` should probably be a non-member.  I like having
  a member function `isEqual`, and having `operator==` (and
  `operator!=`) call it, but making it a `friend` is a perfectly valid
  option as well.
- Not sure what `digitb` is supposed to do.
- You're constructor using `int` isn't compatible with the one using
  `char[]`.  You need to decide whether your internal representation is
  big-endian or little-endian.  Little-endian is probably easier for
  the arithmetic operations, but it means you'll have to process the
  digits in the reverse order in `BigInt( char[] )`.  In fact, you start
  out as if you're going to process the characters in reverse order, but
  you end up going backwards over both arrays, never initializing the end
  of `digit`, and not changing the order.  (You also need to check that
  each `char` really is a digit—using the standard `isdigit`
  function.)

In general, you should be using standard functions whenever they do the
job (and your assignment allows it).  In `BigInt::BigInt( char[] )`, for
example, `new_digit + strlen( new_digit )` will give you an
“iterator” to the `'\0'`.  (Using an iterator to go
backwards is a bit trickier than going forwards, because you're not
allowed to decrement it beyond the front of the array.  Something like:

```
const const* source = new_digits + strlen( new_digits );
while ( source != new_digits ) {
    -- source;
    //  ...
}
```

works well, however.

Comment: Thanks Everyone!  Your info. really helped.

Answer (score 0):

Well I think your implementation of comparing is not correct (i maybe wrong because you haven't specified what is the condition of comparison, so it is my assumption) because:

You are comparing the two numbers in the same passed bigint, see this:

```
bool bigint::operator==(const  bigint& num1)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < MAX; i++)
    {
        if (num1.digit == num1.digit) // it'll be always true
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

So since this is homework, **i am not giving exact solution**, but for method, compare digit by digit and see [this](http://www.functionx.com/cpp/Lesson25.htm) on operator overloading, it should help. Read, try and learn.

For the second question, you need to print 80 digits per line, so run a loop, from start to finish for all characters, and when loop counter reaches 80 (or 79 is you are starting from 0), output a newline character. This is one solution.

And mention requirements clearer next time.